# How to call an executable file directly in notepad++?

Tags: cmd, latex, notepad++

In windows,I use the Notepad++ to write tex file, in the "run..." dialog,I input that:

```
cmd /k D:\CTEX\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\xelatex $(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)
```

then run it,however the result shows that 'xdvipdfmx' is not an executable file. But I am sure that I have add its path to the system environment variable,and when I direct run it in the terminal, it's ok.
So,I want to know what I should do to run it in the notepad++ correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these improvements:

1. enclose paths into quotes to  avoid problems with spaces
2. add **.exe** to executable file name
3. test the full command in command prompt to see if it works (replace `$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)`) with actual file name

please let me know the result

Your example after changes:
`cmd /k "D:\CTEX\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\xelatex.exe" "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"`

Test it in command prompt like:
`cmd /k "D:\CTEX\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\xelatex.exe" "D:\Data\MyDoc1.tex"`